# Retrieve Location coordinates from google maps in R

Tags: r, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to retrieve the locations of a search term from google maps.

[Here's an example with the term "pizza" near London](https://www.google.com.ar/maps/search/pizza/@51.4901791,-0.8851321,8.75z?hl=es-419)

I would like to get the results of latitude and longitude for every place. I've been searching and this is possible if you have the address.

[Here's an example using address.](http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-google-maps-api-and-r/)

However I am interested in using a search term just like you would do when you search for a term in Google Maps.

Comment: The [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) can get you the information you need, but you'll need to write a script to call it from R. `httr` and/or `jsonlite` will be useful.

Comment: @alistaire I'll take a look at it and come back if I have difficulties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went to Google Places API as suggested in comments.
I managed to create an account and get a key.
I wrote a function named `encontrar` that basically searches for places with a keyword in a radius from a center.
I order to get the center I went to google maps and found latitude and longitude for that point. This was very quick to do by hand I don't think I will need to write code for that but be my guest.
So once the center is defined,

```
coordenadas<-c(-34.605424, -58.458499)

encontrar<-function(lugar,radius,keyword){

# radius in meters
#lugar is coordinates from google maps by hand
  coor<-paste(lugar[1],lugar[2],sep=",")
  baseurl<-"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
  google_key<-c(" YOUR KEY HERE")


q<-paste(baseurl,"location=",coor,"&radius=",radius,"&types=food|restaurant&keyword=",keyword,"&key=",google_key, sep="")

print(q)

data1<-fromJSON(q)

lat_long<-data.frame(lat=data1$results$geometry$location$lat,long=data1$results$geometry$location$lng)

#print(data1)

sitios<-data1$results$name

df<-cbind(sitios,lat_long)
return(df)
}


encontrar(lugar = coordenadas,radius = 500,"pizzeria")
```

gives a nice data frame with the places within 500m

It's also worth to mention that `"&types=food|restaurant"` help in this case because the keyword is "pizzeria". It should be changed in other case.

Comment: Ok this works but limited to 20...looking for a workaround with that

Comment: Well yes, that would be awesome but not the workaround I'm looking for. Maybe I can take samples within the city and use the 1000 free query you get per day until the number of unique places converge but just thinking